# Grails - same database for dev, test, prod

Tags: mysql, grails, amazon-rds

For economic reasons (I'm using MySQL on RDS) .. 
Is there a way to host dev, test, prod databases all in the same database? Can you use database table prefixes? or schema?

Note: there will be funds later to break them out into a true 3 server setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure you can.  Mysql is an RDBMS, it *contains* databases, plural.  You would have to create different databases in your mysql instance, like "app_test", "app_dev", "app_prod", and for good measure I would create a separate user and password  for each, and lock down the database to make sure different users cannot modify other databases.

As a matter of practicality, I personally would not let the prod db be anything but production. Too easy to make a mistake and then oops bye bye data.

Comment: Thanks. Was confused by the RDS setup screens. Wasn't clear that you could have more than one database. see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=150329 someone else asking same question

Comment: And it looks like MySQL has no support like MSSQL or Oracle for Schema

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that grails will by default use three schemas, not three databases (as in three servers). So there is no additional cost (as in hardware) involved.
If you use one schema for dev/test/prod, you delete/alter the contents of that schema with every test run which is probably not what you want.